# MongoDB: find one document based on the order of $or values?

Tags: mongodb

`findOne()`:

> If multiple documents satisfy the query, this method returns the first document according to the natural order which reflects the order of documents on the disk.

I need a similar effect as the above, except if multiple documents satisfy the query, it returns the one that comes earliest in the $or array.

```
db.collection.findOne({
     $or: [
         {"apple": "blah"},
         {"orange": "blah"},
         {"grape": "blah"}
     ]
})
```

For example, if these documents all satisfy the above query

```
[
    {"apple": "....", "orange": "....", "grape": "blah"},
    {"apple": "....", "orange": "blah", "grape": "...."}
]
```

it only returns the document that matched `orange` (the second one above), because `orange` comes before `grape` in the $or array. Similarly, if a document matched `apple` then that document would be returned because `apple` comes earlier in the array. How can this be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you basically want to assign a "score" each document and then only return the one with the "highest score". One way to do this would be using the [aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/aggregate/) with an additional [**`$project`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) and [**`$sort`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) stage to your initial query. Then you [**`$limit`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/limit/) the result to the first or "highest" score found:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$match": {
        "$or": [
            { "apple": "blah" },
            { "orange": "blah" },
            { "grape": "blah" }
        ]
    }},
    { "$project": {
        "apple": 1,
        "orange": 1,
        "grape": 1,
        "score": {
            "$add": [
                { "$cond": [{ "$eq": [ "$apple", "blah" ] }, 5, 0 ] },
                { "$cond": [{ "$eq": [ "$orange", "blah" ] }, 3, 0 ] },
                { "$cond": [{ "$eq": [ "$grape", "blah" ] }, 1, 0 ] }
            ]
        }
    }},
    { "$sort": { "score": -1 } },
    { "$limit": 1 }
])
```

That basically gives you the "best match" to your queried items with a singular result. More or less a `.findOne()` operation with a calculated field.